# how to get wall paper name using command?

Tags: windows, dos

I need find out the wall paper name that has been set in windows. using command through command prompt i need to find out wall paper name.consider an example, i have set somepicture.jpg as a wall  paper. now by using a command through command prompt i should be able find the name of the wall paper(somepicture.jpg). is it possible? Please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Win7, path is stored in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper`. You can obtain it using

```
reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper
```

But then you need a bit parsing of returned value.

in WinXP file name is `'C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Wallpaper1.jpg'` (or `bmp` depending on image type).

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for yur reply. do i need execute above command at command prompt? Thanks!